# ext.net how to get two cells values from a row on cell selection of gridpanel?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, extjs, ext.net

i have a question..
  i'm using a gridpanel to show a report, and using cell selection module . 
  i want to get the first two columns values on selection of any other cell..

i tried to upload image but it's not accepted from the site :)

i used the IDproperty in the store , but I have two problems on them , 
     1 - it uses only for one column , not composite key..
     2 - when i collapse groups before the selected row , the ID property returns with wrong value ..

i there any way to get the values of the first and second columns????

here is my code ..

```
    <ext:GridPanel ClientIDMode="Static"  RTL="false"  Layout="FitLayout"  ID="grdUsersRates" runat="server"  MaxHeight="700"  Padding="5"  >
                <HeaderConfig >
                    <Items>
                        <ext:Label ID="Label1" ClientIDMode="Static"  Flex="4" runat="server" Text=""></ext:Label>
                        <ext:Label ID="Label2" ClientIDMode="Static" Flex="3" runat="server"  Text="نتائج البحث"></ext:Label>                            
                    </Items>
                </HeaderConfig>
                <SelectionModel >                        
                    <ext:CellSelectionModel  ID="cellSelectionModel1"  runat="server" >                    
                        <DirectEvents >
                            <Select OnEvent="getCellTaxReturns">
                                <ExtraParams>
                                    <ext:Parameter Name="CurrentPageIndex" Value="#{grdSearchResult}.getStore().currentPage" Mode="Raw" />
                                    <ext:Parameter Name="PageSize" Value="#{grdSearchResult}.store.pageSize" Mode="Raw" />
                                </ExtraParams>
                                <EventMask Msg="برجاء الإنتظار حتى يتم تحميل الإقرارات"  ShowMask="true">

                                </EventMask>
                            </Select>
                        </DirectEvents>
                    </ext:CellSelectionModel>
                </SelectionModel>                 
                <Store >
                    <ext:Store OnReadData="refreshGridView" ID="storeUserRates" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" GroupField="szScanUserName">
                        <Model>
                            <ext:Model ID="Model4" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" >
                                <Fields>
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="nScanUserId" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="szScanUserName" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="szTaxReturnCategoryCode" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="szTaxReturnCategoryDescr" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="nScanTaxReturnCount" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="nScanPaperCount" />
                                </Fields>
                            </ext:Model>
                        </Model>                            
                    </ext:Store>
                </Store>                    
                <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel2" runat="server" RTL="false" ClientIDMode="Static" >
                    <Columns>   
                        <ext:SummaryColumn ID="clScanPaperCount" runat="server" Align="Center" Text="عدد الصفحات" Flex="3" DataIndex="nScanPaperCount" RTL="true" 
                            SummaryType="Sum"
                        >

                        </ext:SummaryColumn>

                        <ext:SummaryColumn ID="clScanTaxReturnCount"  runat="server" Align="Center" Text="عدد الإقرارات" Flex="3" DataIndex="nScanTaxReturnCount"  RTL="true" 
                                                    SummaryType="Sum">

                        </ext:SummaryColumn>

                        <ext:Column  runat="server" Align="Center" Text="نوع الإقرار" Flex="5" DataIndex="szTaxReturnCategoryDescr" RTL="true" ID="clReturnTypeName" >
                        </ext:Column>

                        <ext:Column Hidden="true" runat="server" Align="Center" Text="كود نوع الإقرار" Flex="5" DataIndex="szTaxReturnCategoryCode" RTL="true" ID="clReturnTypeCode" >
                        </ext:Column>

                        <ext:Column runat="server" Align="Center" Text="إسم المستخدم" Flex="5" DataIndex="szScanUserName" RTL="false" ID="clUserName" >
                        </ext:Column>

                        <ext:Column Hidden="true" runat="server" Align="Center" Text="رقم المستخدم" Flex="3" DataIndex="nScanUserId" RTL="true" ID="clUserID" >
                        </ext:Column>

                        <ext:RowNumbererColumn ID="serial" Flex="1" runat="server" Text="مسلسل"  >

                        </ext:RowNumbererColumn> 
                    </Columns>  
                </ColumnModel>
                <TopBar>
                    <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server" RTL="true" >                            
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Button ID="btnShowTotalsOnly" runat="server" Text="إظهار الإجمالى فقط / إظهار التفاصيل" Icon="Anchor" 
                                Handler="#{UserRatesGroupingSummary}[#{UserRatesGroupingSummary}.expanded ? 'collapseAll' : 'expandAll'](); #{UserRatesGroupingSummary}.expanded = !#{UserRatesGroupingSummary}.expanded;"></ext:Button>

                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer></ext:ToolbarSpacer>
                            <ext:ToolbarSeparator></ext:ToolbarSeparator>
                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer></ext:ToolbarSpacer>

                            <ext:Button ID="btnPrintFullGrid" runat="server" Text="طباعة الجدول" Icon="Printer" Handler="this.up('grid').print();"></ext:Button>

                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer></ext:ToolbarSpacer> 

                            <ext:Button ID="btnPrintPageGrid" runat="server" Text="طباعة الصفحة الحالية فقط" Icon="Printer" Handler="this.up('grid').print({currentPageOnly : true });" />
                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer></ext:ToolbarSpacer>
                            <ext:ToolbarSeparator></ext:ToolbarSeparator>
                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer></ext:ToolbarSpacer> 

                            <ext:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="إستخراج نسخة Excel" Icon="PageExcel" ClientIDMode="Static" >
                                <Listeners>
                                    <Click Fn="saveDataOfUserRates" />
                                </Listeners>
                                <DirectEvents>
                                    <Click OnEvent="mainToExcel" IsUpload="true">

                                    </Click>
                                </DirectEvents>
                            </ext:Button>

                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer></ext:ToolbarSpacer> 

                            <ext:Button ID="btnExportToPDF" runat="server" Text="إستخراج نسخة PDF" Icon="PageAttach" ClientIDMode="Static" >

                                <DirectEvents>
                                    <Click OnEvent="mainToPdf"  IsUpload="true"></Click>
                                </DirectEvents>
                            </ext:Button>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Toolbar>
                </TopBar>
<BottomBar>
                    <ext:PagingToolbar RTL="true" ID="grdPagingToolBar" runat="server" EmptyMsg="لا توجد بيانات متاحة الان"  
                                BeforePageText="الصفحة" AfterPageText="من {0}" DisplayMsg="عرض {0} - {1} من{2}">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="lblPageSize" runat="server" Text="حجم الصفحة:"></ext:Label>
                            <ext:ToolbarSpacer ID="grdToolBarSpacer1" runat="server" Width="10"></ext:ToolbarSpacer>
                                <ext:ComboBox ID="cmbxPageSize" runat="server" Width="80">
                                    <Items>
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="15" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="25" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="50" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="100" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="150" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="200" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="250" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="300" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="400" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="500" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="700" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="850" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="1000" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="120" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="1500" />
                                        <ext:ListItem Text="2000" />
                                    </Items>
                                    <SelectedItems>
                                        <ext:ListItem Value="25" />
                                    </SelectedItems>
                                    <Listeners>
                                        <Select Handler=
                                        "#{grdUsersRates}.store.pageSize = parseInt(this.getValue(), 10); #{grdUsersRates}.store.reload();#{UserRatesGroupingSummary}[#{UserRatesGroupingSummary}.expanded ? 'collapseAll' : 'expandAll'](); #{UserRatesGroupingSummary}.expanded = !#{UserRatesGroupingSummary}.expanded;" />
                                    </Listeners>
                                </ext:ComboBox>
                            </Items>
                        <Plugins>
                            <ext:ProgressBarPager ID="grdProgressBarPager" runat="server" ></ext:ProgressBarPager>
                        </Plugins>
                    </ext:PagingToolbar>
                </BottomBar>
                <Features>
                    <ext:GroupingSummary ID="UserRatesGroupingSummary" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                        runat="server" GroupHeaderTplString="{name}" 
                                HideGroupedHeader="true"  StartCollapsed="true"
                                EnableGroupingMenu="true" EnableNoGroups="true" GroupByText="grouping بهذا العمود" 
                                ShowGroupsText="إظهار المجموعات Grouping" >

                    </ext:GroupingSummary>
                        <ext:Summary ID="Summary1" runat="server"  />     
                </Features>
            </ext:GridPanel>
```

i  need to got those values any way , event if there is need to use jquery ..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A record is passed to a Select event according to [the ExtJS docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel-event-select).

Therefore you can get any field of that record.

```
<ext:Parameter Name="someField" Value="record.get('modelFieldName')" Mode="Raw" />
```